# Cannot get html validation to work within Syntastic (gvim)

Tags: vim, syntastic

I am trying to get jshint to work within Syntastic (gvim). The Syntastic wiki says it can be used for html validation. I added following line to my vimrc.

```
let g:syntastic_html_checkers = ['jshint']
```

Available and currently enable checker: jshint is detected.

Now when I try to edit a html file no errors are given.

When I try to use the w3 validation instead:

```
let g:syntastic_html_checkers = ['w3']
```

I get an abnormal error 26.

Can somebody help me? The official readme is confusing and I cannot find much other sources.

Comment: No, jshint is *only* a JavaScript linter. It can be used to check JavaScript in HTML files but it won't lint HTML itself. Use one of the available HTML checkers instead: tidy, validator or w3.

Comment: I tried those, I get abnormal error 26 when using w3. Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: No idea. You should try Syntastic's issue tracker.

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs on syntastic's page: [Scrooloose/syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic),
You can install a checker from github called 'HTML Tidy for HTML5. It's question **3.3**. Then set the exec variable to point to it.

```
g:syntastic_html_tidy_exec = 'path/to/html-tidy'
```

It also says, in that same Q&A, that you can download a java based html checker, run it as a local webserver, and point syntastic at that.

Comment: `brew install tidy-html5` without anything else solved this problem for me.